# Typed variable declaration : Class: JSONObject not found in namespace

Tags: json, jmeter

I am trying to execute below JSON code from Jmeter BeanShell Post processor but I am getting an error
"Typed variable declaration : Class: JSONObject not found in namespace"

We are using JMeter 5.3 version and JSON jar files are available in the lib and lib\ext

```
import java.util.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Criteria;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Filter;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;


JSONObject cartItemsObj = (JSONObject) cartItems.get("C_cartItems");

log.info(cartItemsObj);
```

Error details:

2021-03-03 20:55:19,967 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.*;  import com.jayway.jsonpath.Criteria; import com.jayway.json . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: JSONObject not found in namespace

Comment: Try removing `import java.util.*;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In order to be able to use `JSONObject` class you need to have [org.json.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. I fail to see where and how do you get `cartItems` object
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 you are supposed to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting
4. Groovy has built-in JSON support so if you want to get `C_cartItems` attribute value from the response (assuming that it exists on top level of the JSON you're getting from the server) it can be done as simple as:

   ```
   cartItemsObj = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).C_cartItems

   log.info(cartItemsObj)
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]

More information:

- [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)